# MySQL: left join exclusion

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, innodb

I'm struggling with a MySQL request i cannot seem to find the right syntax.
The design of my database is pretty simple: I have a table **applicant**, a table **internship** and a table **application**. When an applicant applies for an internship, I insert a row into the application table containing two foreign keys linking the applicant and the internship.

**QUESTION**: How can I get the list of all the internships an applicant has not applied for already, knowing the applicant's id?

**SO FAR**: I came up with this query, but that's not it:

```
SELECT internship.* FROM internship LEFT JOIN application
ON application.id_internship = internship.id_internship
WHERE application.id_applicant IS NULL OR application.id_applicant <> 42
GROUP BY application.id_internship
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Have a good day.

[image: database design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the condition for the applicant id in the join and use the `=` operator, so that the joined records are the ones connected to the applicant, then filter out the internships where the join has a match:

```
SELECT
  internship.*
FROM
  internship
  LEFT JOIN application ON application.id_internship = internship.id_internship AND application.id_applicant = 42
WHERE
  application.id_applicant IS NULL
```

There is no need to group the query, as each internship occurs only once in the result.

Comment: That did work !  I never thought about using the condition in the join, that's  pretty clever !

Comment: I allowed myself to edit your answer and switch the '=' with '<>' to make it work. Thanks a lot

Comment: @PierreRoudaut: I changed it back, because that's not how it works. The left join should match the internships that the applicant has applied for, because that is then use to exclude those internships. If you use `<>` it will match all internships that *everyone else* applied for, and those will be excluded, leaving you with the internships that noone applied for, and the ones that noone but the applicant applied for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` operator to do it without a join, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM internship i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM application a
    WHERE i.id_internship = i.id_internship AND application.id_applicant = 42
)
```

The query is self-explanatory: only internships for which the applicant with `id` of `42` did not apply will be selected.

Comment: That did the job! I'm not familiar with the use of EXISTS, but it's quite powerfull !

Comment: Actually, I tried your query, but I still get the internships for which the applicant already applied...